# PHP mkdir() permission denied

Tags: php, rhel7

I keep getting permission denied when using mkdir() in my PHP script.

*mkdir: cannot create directory : Permission denied:*

```
$mount = shell_exec( "mkdir -p {$mntdir}/{$hostname} 2>&1");
```

I try to write to folder

```
/home/user/mnt
```

When I type below in the command line it does work, so which permissions am I missing?

```
php -r "shell_exec('mkdir -p /home/user/mnt/test');"
```

RHEL7/ PHP Version 5.4.16

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is selinux in effect?

Check with command

```
sestatus
```

If it is enforcing - then try setting this parameter

```
setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs true
```

You can also monitor selinux deny messages via

```
sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use php function `mkdir`?

```
if (!mkdir($dir, 0755, true)) {
    die('Failed to create folders...');
}
```

If you have warnings enabled, you will receive warnings if directory already exists or you don't have permissions for it.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the configuration, I assume the problem is the user which runs the PHP script.

When you run the script from shell via command-line PHP, you are running the script as the current logged-in user, which has rights to write to the `/home/user/mnt`.

However, your web server PHP process is running as another user, which does not have write rights, and therefore the creation fails.